# Is there a way to convert between UTF-16 code unit and UTF-32 code unit indices on iOS and/or Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, unicode

I have been given ranges to apply attributes to a string.  The challenge is that the ranges are provided in UTF-32 code units.

is 1 UTF-32 code unit, but NSString treats it as length 2 since it is a composed character of two UTF-16 surrogate pair characters.

^ิ on the other hand is 2 UTF-32 code units, and NSString also treats it as length 2.

I can find simple methods for converting between non-composed and composed.  And between UTF-16 and graphemes -- but not between 16 and 32 code units.

I think the problem is the same as asking:  is there an easy way to detect surrogate pairs from other composed characters on Mac OS X and/or iOS?

Answer (score 2):

The abstraction of `NSString` is UTF-16 "characters". If you want UTF-32, then it's no longer a string from Cocoa's point of view; it's a data buffer. So, what you're looking for is:

```
NSData* utf32Data = [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
uint32_t* utf32 = (uint32_t*)[utf32Data bytes];
NSUInteger count = [utf32Data length] / sizeof(utf32[0]);
```

then iterate over the `count` elements of the `utf32` array.

---

Here's an untested category on `NSString` for converting a range:

```
@interface NSString (UTF32Range)

- (NSRange) rangeFromUTF32Range:(NSRange)range;

@end

@implementation NSString (UTF32Range)

- (NSRange) rangeFromUTF32Range:(NSRange)range
{
    NSUInteger len = self.length;
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    while (i < range.location && i < len)
    {
        unichar u = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (CFStringIsSurrogateHighCharacter(u))
        {
            range.location++;
            i++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (i < range.length && i < len)
    {
        unichar u = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (CFStringIsSurrogateHighCharacter(u))
        {
            range.length++;
            i++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return range;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, manually iterating over a data buffer works, with the downside that all NSString functions/methods are unavailable. The goal is to find a method that allows using the NSString and NSRange functionality of cocoa, but with UTF-32 instead of NSString's native UTF-16.

Comment: You will have to iterate over the UTF-16 code units and detect surrogate pairs. It's not hard. As you go, you would adjust the UTF-32-based range to compensate.

Comment: I have added some untested code for doing what I suggest. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I have code for doing this (and many other things with UTF-32 strings) -- but manually reimplementing all of NSString is time consuming, error prone, and probably much less performant than using the the 20 year old tried and true library we already have.